# Problem accessing routes from a module that inherits from ModuleWidget

Tags: android, flutter, routes, dart-pub, modular

```
class SearchModule extends ModuleWidget {
  @override
  List<Bind> get binds => [
        Bind((i) => SearchController()),
      ];

  @override
  List<Router> get routers => [
        Router(Modular.initialRoute, child: (_, args) => SearchPage()),
        Router("teacher", child: (_, args) => TeacherListPage()),
      ];

  @override
  Widget get view => SearchPage();

  static Inject get to => Inject<SearchModule>.of();
}
```

I can't access the "teacher" route for this module. That is, I cannot navigate to this route using the method `Modular.to.pushNamed('/teacher', arguments: TeacherListPage())`

I get the following error .: `Could not find a generator for route RouteSettings("/teacher", TeacherListPage) in the _WidgetsAppState.`

Can anyone give me a light?? kkk

Follow the flow of the modules.:

```
I/flutter (13793): -- AppModule INITIALIZED
I/flutter (13793): -- HomeModule INITIALIZED
I/flutter (13793): -- ReviewsModule INITIALIZED
I/flutter (13793): -- HomeModule DISPOSED
I/flutter (13793): -- SearchModule INITIALIZED
```

Follows the structure of the modules .:

```
<------------------------------------------------------------------------>

class AppModule extends MainModule {
  @override
  List<Bind> get binds => [
        Bind((i) => TeacherListController()),
        Bind((i) => ReviewsContentController()),
        Bind((i) => SigninController()),
        Bind((i) => SignupController()),
        Bind((i) => AppController()),
      ];

  @override
  List<Router> get routers => [
        Router(Modular.initialRoute, module: HomeModule()),
        Router('/reviews', module: ReviewsModule()),
      ];

  @override
  Widget get bootstrap => AppWidget();

  static Inject get to => Inject<AppModule>.of();
}

<------------------------------------------------------------------------>

class HomeModule extends ChildModule {
  @override
  List<Bind> get binds => [
        Bind((i) => HomeController()),
      ];

  @override
  List<Router> get routers => [
        Router(Modular.initialRoute, child: (_, args) => HomePage()),
        Router("signUp", child: (_, args) => SignupPage()),
        Router("signIn", child: (_, args) => SigninPage()),
      ];

  static Inject get to => Inject<HomeModule>.of();
}

<------------------------------------------------------------------------>

class ReviewsModule extends ChildModule {
  @override
  List<Bind> get binds => [
        Bind((i) => ReviewsController()),
      ];

  @override
  List<Router> get routers => [
        Router(Modular.initialRoute, child: (_, args) => ReviewsPage()),
      ];

  static Inject get to => Inject<ReviewsModule>.of();
}

<------------------------------------------------------------------------>

class SearchModule extends ModuleWidget {
  @override
  List<Bind> get binds => [
        Bind((i) => SearchController()),
      ];

  @override
  List<Router> get routers => [
        Router(Modular.initialRoute, child: (_, args) => SearchPage()),
        Router("teacher", child: (_, args) => TeacherListPage()),
      ];

  @override
  Widget get view => SearchPage();

  static Inject get to => Inject<SearchModule>.of();
}

<------------------------------------------------------------------------>
```

Comment: I didn't read the full code, but can you make sure that it isn't because at someplaces you are using the route name as `teacher`, and then trying to push it with name `/teacher`.

Comment: Negative! But tkx ;)

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I was wrongly calling the route.

When I tried to call the route that was inside the SearchModule module, I was not making the correct path to it, that is, I was calling it as follows:

```
Modular.to.pushNamed('/teacher')
```

However, when it is called that way, the first thing Modular does is check if this route exists in the AppModule Module, and as shown above, there is only the route

```
Router('/reviews', module: ReviewsModule()),
```

Therefore, the correct way to navigate would be to go "inside" the modules until you reach the SearchModule module which has the route for teacher. Remembering that I had to add within the ReviewsModule module the route for SearchModule that finally has the route for teacher.

Soon I had to add,

```
Router('/search', module: SearchModule()),
```

And finally, the correct call would be,

```
Modular.to.pushNamed('/reviews/search/teacher')
```